# What is a Spike Word™?

Tags: word, knowledge, pattern, word-property

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee)*

If a word satisfies a certain property it is called a **Spike Word™**. Here are some examples:

| Spike Words™ | Not Spike Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| MAGNUM | RAIN |
| LINK | DEVICE |
| VANITY | FALLEN |
| KING | APEX |
| DUBSTEP | ART |
| VICTOR | SIMPLE |
| SICK | FROZEN |
| MUNCHKIN | HOBBIT |
| CHRONICLE | ELECTRONIC |
| VIXEN | HUNTER |

```
Spike Words™,Not Spike Words™
MAGNUM,RAIN
LINK,DEVICE
VANITY,FALLEN
KING,APEX
DUBSTEP,ART
VICTOR,SIMPLE
SICK,FROZEN
MUNCHKIN,HOBBIT
CHRONICLE,ELECTRONIC
VIXEN,HUNTER
```

What is the rule to tell whether a word is a Spike Word™ or not? Why is it called a Spike Word™? (Note that each word can be tested on its own.)

---

> Technically I should have wrote *L1NK* and not *LINK*, *S1MPLE* and not *SIMPLE*…

Comment: Note; Qbrfa'g nccrne gb or nobhg fcrpvsvp yrggref (TXL va fcvxr bayl, SM va aba-fcvxr bayl ohg zbfg bs gurfr bayl nccrne bapr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word is a Spike Word™ if...

> ...they are names of Valorant pro-players. A [spike](https://valorant.fandom.com/wiki/Spike) is an object in the game.

Re: hint:

> The names of the players are stylized as [L1NK](https://liquipedia.net/valorant/L1NK) and [s1mple](https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple). Non-Spike Words™ play Counter-Strike, which involves a bomb instead of a spike.

Comment: Aha, was about to come in. rot13(V oryvrir gur fcvxr cynlref ner fcrpvsvpnyyl sbezre PFTB cynlref gung ner abj Inybenag cebf.)

Comment: @MrSethward rot13(I1kra qbrfa'g svg gung nppbeqvat gb gurve jvxv.)

Comment: Correct. rot13(V gbbx gur cynlre anzrf sebz grnzf jub cynlrq va gur tnzrf' erprag jbeyq punzcvbafuvcf (Punzcvbaf Oreyva naq gur Fgbpxubyz Znwbe).)